# D3.js on Canvas hover on node to select its links

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

First off, i've seen questions like this posted several times, but they are all based on SVG, classes and CSS. I'm aiming at solving this using canvas because my final force layout will use 1000+ nodes and svg just doesn't cut it. Also, I have a background in programming but am total n00b to d3. So maybe i'm just missing something obvious.

Here's my current code:
http://bl.ocks.org/gonzam88/3ff2f33975ca8258f4aa9484be4255ce

I guess on mouseover I have to loop all links and check if either source or target matched the current node, but after many attempts i'm not too sure how to achieve this, and how to change specific links properties (when not using SVG).

I feel i'm close but not just there :)

Thanks for reading and hope my english is ok!

**UPDATE 1**

I've managed to detect links related to hovered node, but when I try to change its stroke it changes every stroke in my graph.

check:
http://blockbuilder.org/gonzam88/9d48b4346fadb6b719a9ce9efb98a899

In this example I only want each group to change to blue line. But both 'groups' are being changed.
Links are drawn on line 140 and my color function is on line 57. How do set stroke color to specific links?

Comment: Take a look @ quad tree. using the algorithm you will not have to traverse through all the nodes to check if current node matches.

Comment: thanks @cyril but quad tree is for proximity. I'm looking to change specific line's color according to their link (on canvas)